# What is the current standard for complete encryption of user information?

Tags: encryption, web-application, web-browser

If one were to design a social media service, but with guaranteed encrypted privacy of all aspects of one's data, what are the proper technologies to employ for all of

1.) On disk storage

2.) Transport

3.) User interface

With the goal of maintaining total privacy of the data for the user's access only, based on an RSA key.

Comment: My suggestion would be to rely on access control instead of simply relying on encryption. Simply encrypting the data and only letting a user being able to decrypt it would present challenges when working on different granularities of data sharing. (I want to share a post with all my friends, I want to share another post with just 2-3 friends of mine etc)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "maintaining privacy" and "all aspects of one's data?"   In order to get any sort of social media functionality, there is going to be a trade off in terms of privacy.

Comment: The idea would be to have a place where a user can keep a complete digital record of their lives such as Facebook, but with that data kept entirely private. The user could then create "snapshots" of certain portions of their data to share with others.

Comment: The key difference being that complete integrity of data privacy is maintained by the user from the point of upload. The service provider has no knowledge of any content.

Comment: It sounds like you want something along the lines of how some online password managers work. Users provide a master paraphrase that is used to encrypt the data. The key is never available to the password management service owners. Look into LastPass, their approach may provide some insight into what your are trying to achieve. https://www.lastpass.com/how-it-works